# How can I sum the combined responses of multiple levels of one factor

Tags: r

Here is a piece of my dataset:

```
Plot Rate Rep Plant Tuber Weight
1    101    1   1     1     1  179.4
2    101    1   1     1     2   99.4
3    101    1   1     1     3   72.4
4    101    1   1     1     4  111.5
5    101    1   1     1     5   44.9
6    101    1   1     1     6   55.3
7    101    1   1     1     7   12.6
8    101    1   1     1     8  106.7
9    101    1   1     1     9   96.7
10   101    1   1     1    10   52.5
11   101    1   1     2     1  151.1
12   101    1   1     2     2  171.7
13   101    1   1     2     3   93.0
14   101    1   1     2     4   82.4
15   101    1   1     2     5  143.9
16   101    1   1     2     6  115.6
17   101    1   1     2     7  141.3
18   101    1   1     2     8   72.6
19   101    1   1     2     9   97.2
20   101    1   1     2    10  146.8
21   101    1   1     2    11  104.0
22   101    1   1     2    12  121.6
23   101    1   1     3     1  150.9
24   101    1   1     3     2   47.1
25   101    1   1     3     3   59.6
26   101    1   1     3     4   94.2
27   101    1   1     3     5  167.4
28   101    1   1     3     6   55.2
29   101    1   1     3     7   21.8
30   101    1   1     3     8   79.6
31   101    1   1     3     9   92.2
32   101    1   1     3    10   78.0
33   101    1   1     3    11   61.8
34   101    1   1     3    12    9.5
35   101    1   1     3    13    2.7
36   101    1   1     3    14    3.8
37   101    1   1     3    15    1.1
38   103    2   1     1     1   24.8
39   103    2   1     1     2   70.1
40   103    2   1     1     3   90.7
41   103    2   1     1     4   75.1
42   103    2   1     1     5   97.9
43   103    2   1     1     6   44.6
44   103    2   1     1     7   65.1
45   103    2   1     1     8   74.5
46   103    2   1     1     9    6.2
47   103    2   1     1    10    7.4
48   103    2   1     1    11   46.1
49   103    2   1     1    12   43.8
50   103    2   1     1    13   61.8
51   103    2   1     1    14   88.2
52   103    2   1     1    15   64.4
53   103    2   1     1    16   35.0
54   103    2   1     1    17    6.0
55   103    2   1     1    18    6.4
56   103    2   1     1    19   55.2
57   103    2   1     1    20   12.1
58   103    2   1     1    21    2.2
59   103    2   1     1    22    4.6
60   103    2   1     1    23    2.3
61   103    2   1     2     1   76.2
62   103    2   1     2     2   63.2
63   103    2   1     2     3   85.3
64   103    2   1     2     4    1.3
65   103    2   1     2     5   59.7
66   103    2   1     2     6   94.9
67   103    2   1     2     7    1.2
68   103    2   1     3     1  103.1
69   103    2   1     3     2    1.6
70   103    2   1     3     3   52.9
71   103    2   1     3     4  101.7
72   103    2   1     3     5   68.5
73   103    2   1     3     6   74.1
74   103    2   1     3     7  106.0
75   103    2   1     3     8   62.7
76   103    2   1     3     9   65.0
77   103    2   1     3    10   47.5
78   103    2   1     3    11    1.2
79   103    2   1     3    12    5.3
80   103    2   1     3    13    8.3
81   103    2   1     3    14    5.5
82   103    2   1     3    15    2.5
83   104    3   1     1     1  150.3
84   104    3   1     1     2  218.8
85   104    3   1     1     3  149.4
86   104    3   1     1     4  144.7
87   104    3   1     1     5  112.5
88   104    3   1     1     6  144.5
89   104    3   1     1     7  139.0
90   104    3   1     1     8  156.9
91   104    3   1     1     9  120.2
92   104    3   1     1    10   46.3
93   104    3   1     1    11   43.4
94   104    3   1     1    12   81.3
95   104    3   1     1    13    7.1
96   104    3   1     1    14   33.3
97   104    3   1     1    15   31.2
98   104    3   1     1    16   12.8
99   104    3   1     1    17    1.5
100  104    3   1     1    18  116.9
101  104    3   1     1    19   52.5
102  104    3   1     2     1   11.5
103  104    3   1     2     2  130.0
104  104    3   1     2     3     NA
105  104    3   1     2     4  125.9
106  104    3   1     2     5  103.6
107  104    3   1     2     6   43.0
108  104    3   1     2     7   79.0
109  104    3   1     2     8   79.4
110  104    3   1     2     9   51.1
111  104    3   1     2    10    1.9
112  104    3   1     2    11    4.5
113  104    3   1     2    12   17.2
114  104    3   1     2    13   58.2
115  104    3   1     2    14   71.6
116  104    3   1     2    15   80.4
117  104    3   1     2    16   44.1
118  104    3   1     2    17   62.4
119  104    3   1     2    18   52.9
120  104    3   1     2    19   28.0
121  104    3   1     2    20   89.4
122  104    3   1     2    21   62.7
123  104    3   1     2    22   55.5
124  104    3   1     2    23    0.8
125  104    3   1     2    24   22.5
126  104    3   1     2    25    2.5
127  104    3   1     2    26    1.6
128  104    3   1     2    27   46.6
129  104    3   1     3     1  191.9
130  104    3   1     3     2  153.2
131  104    3   1     3     3  137.0
132  104    3   1     3     4   90.8
133  104    3   1     3     5  152.8
134  104    3   1     3     6   69.2
135  104    3   1     3     7   11.6
136  104    3   1     3     8   58.7
137  104    3   1     3     9   53.2
138  104    3   1     3    10   68.4
139  104    3   1     3    11   46.0
140  104    3   1     3    12   75.6
141  104    3   1     3    13   68.9
142  104    3   1     3    14   94.8
143  104    3   1     3    15   89.7
```

This covers one of the four reps in my overall dataset. I am looking for a way to get the total collective tuber weight of the three collected plants, averaged between the four reps, for each rate. To be clear, I want to have the weight of all tubers for all 3 of the plants of each Rate/Rep combination added into one final value, then I want to get the average of this final value between the 4 unique Reps (repetitions) that make up each of the 4 Rates.

When calculating the first two reps of rate 1 by hand, I get the following:

```
  Rate Rep TotalResponse
1    1   1        3197.5
2    1   2        2367.4
```

To be as clear as possible, the "TotalResponse" column shows the total sum of the "Weight" responses for each tuber in all three plants of that unique Rate/Rep combination.

When taking the average of those two responses, I get this:

```
Rate AvgResponse
1    1   2782.4
```

In reality, I need to do the first step for all 4 reps and not just 2 of them, and then I need the final table to have this average response for each of the 4 rates.

```
Rate AvgResponse
1    1   2782.4
2    1   xxxx
3    1   xxxx
4    1   xxxx
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to group by 'Rate', 'Rep', get the `sum` of 'Weight', then do a group by 'Rate' and return the `mean` of 'TotalResponse'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Rate, Rep) %>%
    summarise(TotalResponse = sum(Weight, na.rm = TRUE),
      .groups = 'drop_last') %>%
    group_by(Rate) %>% 
    summarise(AvgResponse = mean(TotalResponse))
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Akrun, you have been really helpful. This seems really close, although something is a little off. The portion `data %>% group_by(Rate, Rep) %>% summarise(TotalResponse = sum(Weight, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop_last')` gives the correct sums for each rep, but the last line (where you average for the four reps) does not give correct averages. Do you know what may be wrong?

Comment: I thought you wanted to group by 'Rep' instead of Rate here, as you want to average the 3 'Rate' values

Comment: Sorry, I may have been unclear. I wanted to average the 4 reps together for each rate. I changed the second to last line to `group_by(Rate) ` and it works perfectly now. Thanks so much again for all the help

Comment: @Trev I changed.  The results were not matching with 'Rate' as group by though